# How to get a specific element in an array stored as a FieldValue in Firestore

Tags: android, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I stored an array of customized class like "Patient" in a Document Field. It stored properly but now when I am trying to download it to android studio it seems like this in the log statement:-

> [{"appointmentnumber"=26, "name"="Neeraj Aggarwal",
>   "phonenumber"="+917988081391"},  {appointmentnumber=27, name=Aaskah
>   Sharma, phonenumber=+917988081391},  {appointmentnumber=28, name=Mohit
>   sskm, phonenumber=+917988081391}]

It seems like an Array but I am not being able to apply any property of array on this. Like when I tried to get this array's first element like `ArrayName[0]` then it shows error like:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap` cannot be cast to com.example.reception.Patient
(reception my project name and Patient as you know is customized class name)

Also I don't know how to get the value of a specific element in the array stored as a fieldvalue. Like we can extract a specific value of map by documentsnapshot.get("Fieldname.Keyname"), is there any method like this to get the element on a specific position in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase solved my problem. Their answer is like this:-

> Firebase Support
>
> 10:56 AM (29 minutes ago)

to me

> Hello Neeraj,
>
> I'm Ian, here to answer any questions you may have when it comes to using Firestore for Android.
>
> If you use the snapshot.get() method on a field containing an array of objects, the Android SDK will return that value as a Java List of HashMap objects. There's currently no way to override this behavior, so you may need to manually get each key-value pair and set the value to a Patient object.
>
> With that said, it is possible to convert the entirety of the document snapshot into a Java object in one go, without needing to use a method like snapshot.get(). Assuming your Doctor class looks something like this:
>
> ```
> public class Doctor {
>     private List<Patient> patients;
>     //other variables
>
>     //Constructor must be empty
>     public Doctor() {}
>
>     public List<Patient> getPatients() {
>         return patients;
>     }
>
>     public void setPatients(List<Patient> patients) {
>         this.patients = patients;
>     }
> ```
>
> You can convert your document snapshot into the Doctor object with just one line of code:
>
> ```
> Doctor doctor = snapshot.toObject(Doctor.class);
> ```
>
> From there, you can get your Java List of patients, and then perform your computation on the patient data as intended.

So all the trick was just to use toObject method.